# Trouble understanding extra table reasoning in setting up SQL tables, can someone try to explain clearly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the need to set up two dropdown selections, and I am having trouble with understanding the solutions I have.

**My Situation**
I have a product selection, that will then populate a color selection based on the product.  Multiple products will have some of the same colors.

Since it seems an SQL database can't contain array values in columns easily (or maybe it can, but I haven't found a good solution that returned correct results), I searched some alternative solutions.  The one I found suggested making three tables, a PRODUCT_ID table, a COLOR_ID table, and a PRODUCT_COLOR table.

I don't understand why that would be easier or less work when adding either more products or colors.  Below is the solution that very closely mirrored what I need, but why would you do it that way, instead of setting it up in only two tables and then using something like `SELECT color FROM COLORS where PRODUCT_ID = ID` where the ID value is the selected value from the product selection, in your query? I have added additional products and colors to illustrate it in a way that seems like it's correct based on the information I have as I add more products/colors.  It seems like that solution just adds a third table for the colors and then you would have the same setup in the **PRODUCT/COLOR** table as the **COLORS** table in my first idea?

Is there a way I don't know of that allows you to use arrays in a single column so you only have to list one instance of the color and then all product IDs that would be associated with the color?  I know this is a different question to my first but I was just curious if it was possible to reduce the amount of lines and columns so that I wouldn't have to manually set up a ton of rows for 100+ products and multiple colors per product or additional tables that feel redundant for no reason.  Is the third table a security thing or just to add in availability? I don't need availability but I also saw a similar solution that cross referenced diseases and symptoms with the same idea of three tables, one DISEASES, one SYMPTOMS, and one DISEASES_V_SYMPTOMS using ids

--MY IDEA--

**PRODUCT**

| Product | ID |
| --- | --- |
| T-shirt | 1 |
| Hoodie | 2 |

**COLORS**

| color | PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Red | 2 |
| Green | 1 |
| Green | 2 |
| Blue | 1 |

--SOLUTION CODE PROBLEM--
Wouldn't the following produce something similar to this setup?

**PRODUCT**

| Product | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Tshirt | 1 |
| Hoodie | 2 |

**COLOR**

| COLOR | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Green | 2 |
| Blue | 3 |

**PRODUCT/COLOR**

| PRODUCT_ID | COLOR_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

```
CREATE TABLE [Product]
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,Name NVARCHAR(250)
)

CREATE TABLE [Colour]
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,Colour NVARCHAR(250)
)

CREATE TABLE [Product_Colour_Availability] -- Many to Many relationship table
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,Product_ID INT
,Colour_ID INT
,Available bit -- 1=available, 0=not available
)

--
-- Insert some data for a single product (T-Shirt) that will be both red and blue.

INSERT INTO [Product] (Name)
VALUES ('T-Shirt')

INSERT INTO [Colour] (Colour)
VALUES ('Red'), ('Blue')

INSERT INTO [Product_Colour_Availability] ([Product_ID], [Colour_ID])
VALUES (1,1,1), (1,2,1)

-- Get availability info about a specific product:

SELECT P.[ID] AS 'Product ID'
,P.[Name] AS 'Product Name'
,C.[Colour] AS 'Product Colour'
,PCA.[Available] AS 'Availability'
FROM [Product_Colour_Availability] PCA
LEFT JOIN [Product] P ON PCA.Product_ID=P.[ID]
LEFT JOIN [Colour] C ON PCA.Colour_ID=C.[ID]
WHERE P.[ID] = 1
```

Comment: It's a good question - well worth asking.  I'm sure you'll get a range of different answers that certainly won't lead to a single conclusion.  Traditionally, "relational" databases are just that - databases that contain tables of data that (most commonly) have relationships between themselves (like your example of Colour, Product, Colour_Product).  It's true that in many recent versions of different database servers (SQL Server included) you can store "arrays" of data, by storing (for example) Json or Xml data.

Comment: So - would it be possible to have a single column, within your Colour table, that holds an "array" of the Product IDs that are applicable to that colour?  Yes, it would.  Is that the ideal implementation of that relationship?  I would argue, no.  Reality is, it's still far more cumbersome to actually query data that is held as Json or Xml (in a table cell), than it is to just query separate, related tables.  Does that mean I'm still "old skool"?  Maybe, I don't know.  If you want to give it a go, then go right ahead.  Test both approaches and see which one suits you best!

Comment: Honestly I'm fine with creating multiple tables as I can't seem to get the query to read an array appropriately anyway, but had seen solutions with one table relating only to information in another table that they then suggested using a third linking table and that it would be easier that way to add one row to one table and use it, but in my head it seems you would have to do the same amount of work adding to one table and then adding all of the linking rows as you would with just two tables with one of them just having additional rows.

Comment: So I just was curious about the reasoning for three tables.  It makes sense if you also need size or stock related but if you only needed to relate a product to the colours available for that product, why would you create a third table?  Wouldn't it be the same amount of rows, if not less to just have multiple rows of colour with one additional column to link a product id to a colour id in two tables, instead of a product id/name, a colour id/name, and then a third table with product id and colour id with colour availability? Wouldn't that still just link product id and colour id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't attempt to store arrays in column values. You can probably do it with comma-separated lists, but you definitively defeat SQL query performance optimizations by doing that. The people who will put your database into production will curse your name. Loudly. For a long time. (Ask me how I know this sometime :-)

You have [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model): things in the physical world that you want to model with rows in your database. Those things have relationships between them.

Your three-table solution includes two entity tables (`Product` and `Colour`). And, it looks like it includes a so-called [junction table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106001/are-junction-tables-a-good-practice) that allows you to construct a many-to-many relationship between the entities.  Why is this good?  It makes your database a bit smaller and easier to search.

But you have correctly observed that you don't run out of "small", "red" or "t-shirt", you run out of "small red t-shirts". So, your most important entity, the one physical thing you must model correctly if you want to sell stuff, is your Stock-Keeping Unit. `SKU`

So your question comes down to this: What attributes do you want on your SKU entities?  Maybe something like this?

```
SKU_id  num_in_stock  Size_id  Colour_id  Product_id  description

 1234          7         1         1         1   Small red t-shirt
 1235          0         2         1         1   Medium red t-shirt
 1248          4         3         2         2   Large green hoodie
```

You can search by colour, size, or product using the `_id` values.  Or, you can just use text descriptions and search for products with slow SQL like this.

```
description LIKE '%green%'
```

Your decisions about this are driven by how you want to organize your product presentation and search functions.

Comment: Really solid explanation here. The long and short of it is that SQL is intended to have a single value per table cell. When you have several things that can have several values, you can either 1)hacky things to track them all or 2) use a junction / relationship table to store the different relationships. I can confirm with O. Jones, I am working in a legacy system right now that has a LOT of CSV where we should have junction tables for many to many relationships and its tough to get them out once they're in.

Comment: So then having three tables would only really be necessary if you need to have three different entities?  If I am creating a database for a product order form that doesn't base itself on stock availability because it is to be ordered from a manufacturer, then it would be fine to just use the two table solution of having a product and colour table?   I had just seen the two tables and one linking or junction table used in solutions where there are only two properties that need to be related, like in the disease/symptom setup that they also said to use three tables.

Comment: In my scenario, we need to fill out a form with the client that we just need to know the paver type and the colour that they want, so I just need to link the paver id to the available colours for that paver.  It might be worth noting that in my situation, I am just creating a list that tells the inventory controller what products the client has chosen, and necessary quantities and the actual order form come from a different program. Unrelated, I worked retail for years and never knew or sought the meaning of SKU so you taught me two things today

Comment: I almost forgot to mention that with mine, several different types of products will use the same colours, as the same manufacturers create pavers, wall block, coping, caps, etc in a variety of the same colors. Each will exist in different areas of the form.  Most colours overlap in some place, so I was trying to find an easier way to link colours to various products.  Will I just need several different linking tables for each product category to link to the available colours then?

Comment: Honestly, I think the answer demonstrates that have tables to define the base entities (product, colour), and separate tables to define relationships (product/colour) is the easiest way

Comment: Sounds like "colour" in your world is a standardized thing that yuor customers really care about getting exactly right (like Pantone colors in printing). That's a perfect application for its own table. But, seriously, you might want to check whether WordPress/Woocommerce, or shopify, or something, can handle this for you. They've had a lot of opportunity to refine all this.

Comment: I'll check it out, but had been unable to find something that works the way my employer wants.  Thanks for the help!